# Exit NSThread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

how to exit thread while its in running mode...when i use NSThread exit my app get hanged...
Can any one help me ? what could i use here to exit thread or close thread

Thanks Its my first post here.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909283/how-to-exit-nsthread

Comment: Agree with Brad, and that question has a pretty good answer that is more substantial than the one currently shown here.

Answer (score 6):

The routine you're looking for is `return`.

The thread will terminate when the function that you launched it with finishes. You don't need to terminate the NSThread; it will handle that itself. You just need to return from the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a way to cancel a thread once you've started it. It's all in the set up. Here's an example:

- (

  void) doCalculation{
  /* Do your calculation here */
  }

  - (void) calculationThreadEntry{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; NSUInteger counter = 0;
    while ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled] == NO){
    [self doCalculation];
    counter++;
    if (counter >= 1000){ break;
    } }
    [pool release]; }
    application:(UIApplication *)application
  - (BOOL)
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    /* Start the thread */
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(calculationThreadEntry)
    toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    // Override point for customization after application launch. [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }

In this example, the loop is conditioned on the thread being in a non-cancelled state.