# How to stop a NSThread in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsthread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exit NSThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909283/how-to-exit-nsthread)

I have called a method using NSthread. I want to stop the thread on a click event of button. How can I achieve that?

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(playVideo) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : [How to exit NSThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909283/how-to-exit-nsthread)

Answer (score 1):

Try the the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW10) for Threading, or better yet use `NSOperation` to perform the `playVideo` maintain a reference to the operation in your viewController and send a `cancel` message to the operation. Refer to the documentation[NSOperation documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW18)