# How to stop current running thread

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I am creating new thread on one button click On other button click i want to stop that thread How to implement it...

I have used

```
[NSThread exit];
```

but it freezes my UI.....

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3153045/1603234)'s a good answer.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use    `-[NSThread cancel]`

**- (void)cancel**

```
       Changes the cancelled state of the receiver to indicate that it should exit.
```

Check the cancellation through `-[NSThread isCancelled]`

or

**exit**

Terminates the current thread.

```
+ (void)exit
```

This method uses the currentThread class method to access the current thread. Before exiting the thread, this method posts the **NSThreadWillExitNotification** with the thread being exited to the default notification center. Because notifications are delivered synchronously, all observers of **NSThreadWillExitNotification** are guaranteed to receive the notification before the thread exits.

Invoking this method should be avoided as it does not give your thread a chance to clean up any resources it allocated during its execution.